# R: Reorganise 2D list of dataframes into one dataframe

Tags: r, list, dataframe

This is possibly a simple question, but most of my R experience is with dataframes and dplyr. I have list of lists, where the inner list contains one 'information' dataframe and one 'results' dataframe (see example below).

```
# Sample code for my data structure
data <- list(
  list(data.frame(subject = "A", year = 2016),
       data.frame(results = c(1, 2, 3), time = c(4, 5, 6))
  ),
  list(data.frame(subject = "B", year = 2017),
       data.frame(results = c(7, 8, 9), time = c(10, 11, 12))
  )
)
```

While this has been great for analysing data in inner lists, I've struggled  to do 'cross-list' analysis. What I'm trying to do is reshape my data as shown below.

```
# Dataframes in lists in lists (current)
    [[1]]
    [[1]][[1]]
      subject year
    1       A 2016
    [[1]][[2]]
      results time
    1       1    4
    2       2    5
    3       3    6
    [[2]]
    [[2]][[1]]
      subject year
    1       B 2017
    [[2]][[2]]

# Single dataframe (goal)
      subject year results time
    1       A 2016       1    4
    2       A 2016       2    5
    3       A 2016       3    6
    4       B 2017       7   10
    5       B 2017       8   11
    6       B 2017       9   12
```

I've searched online already, but most of the solutions are of a single list of dataframes not lists of lists.

My best effort so far is using for loops (see below), but as my actual data is *much* larger (both rows and columns) I'm trying to work out a more efficient solution.

```
df = data.frame()
for (i in (1:length(data))) {
  df = rbind(df,
             cbind(data[[i]][[1]], data[[i]][[2]]))
}
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are familiar with `dplyr`, try this:

```
bind_rows(lapply(data,function(i)do.call(cbind,i)))
```

PS. I found `bind_cols` does not work well. Maybe it is a little bug?

Answer (score 1):

Might be:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(1:length(data), 
                      function(i) do.call(cbind, data[[i]])
                      )
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

package:data.table does this well with rbindlist(..., fill = TRUE). Just convert back to data.frame when you're done.